# No results displayed because all values equal 0 - Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am on kibana 5 and I have pie chart visualization, it says "No results displayed because all values equal 0".

On discover tab everything is fine and ChannelID field is searchable and aggregatable.

Any ideas?

Screens:

[kibana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x38yV.png)

[kibana2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZ61h.png)

Answer (score 5):

> **No results displayed because all values equal 0**

means that the documents were found but the metric calculates 0 for every slice in your pie chart (probably sum of fields that are all 0). This cannot be displayed. If the values are 0 pie can't be drawn, there could be certain reasons.

- Make sure you've set your aggregation correctly.
- Make sure your metric is correct (by default it's count
  which should work)
- Make sure the time range which is located in the top right corner is set so you get
  some results back (by default its last 15 minutes/give it a change)

You might want to have a look at this [ticket](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/2863). Hope it helps!

Comment: Spent like 30 minutes trying to figure out why I was getting the same 0 count, then your last reason popped just right! Good one!